# Live Streaming on iPhone / Android : RTMP - HTTP

Tags: android, iphone, ios5, rtmp, http-live-streaming

We are planning to develop a mobile app which would allow users to view live streamings, broadcast live streaming from iPhone / Android device.

We have red5 set up on the server for RTMP streaming on our website. But, I am not sure if we can use RTMP streaming on iOS / Android. I have read on Apple's documentation saying that we need to use HTTP Live Streaming.

It's bit confusing on how to implement live streaming in case RTMP and HTTP.

**Scenario one:** How to view RTMP Live streaming [Initiated from swf file] on iPhone / Android devices. How to convert RTMP to HTTP. I have heard about Xuggler but not sure if its recommended.

**Scenario two:** How to broadcast HTTP Live streaming from iPhone / Android? Is there any API available? Also, how to view HTTP live streaming [initiated from iPhone / Android] on website's flash swf file. Is swf file player capable of playing HTTP streaming? I haven't tested this yet.

I wonder how iOs app like ustream has implemented live streaming but we do not want to use third party streaming service. We are looking for our own custom solution.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you but I can at least confirm that RTMP streaming is not (and will probably never be) available for iOS because it is related to Adobe Flash (which is itself not now and unlikely to ever be supported on iOS).

Comment: There are services that do transcoding for iOS like myRBM.tv. I'm very interested in finding a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can view a Live stream initiated from an android phone in the browser using a flash plugin. Even i am working on a similar project and i have managed to stream video from the device to the browser. You can check out this open source project for reference -

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at the

[FlvStreamer](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/flvstreamer/)

This is a C Library replacement for one portion of your question. Check whether this C library is compatible with the LLVM and check once whether this is workable for you.

also check the copy-protection clause for this in the below link and decide for the use,

[Wiki copy protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol#Client_software)

Check and update if you find any answer please.